# Multiple header freeze using Jquery.freezeHeader()

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a requirement to freeze header , For this I used JQUERY plugin freezeheader.js.
And the following line of code has been added.

```
$("#summarytab").freezeHeader();
```

The above line works perfectly for one page. In my second page i have two headers in the table.
The above piece of code works only for first header.

Is there any way to freeze the two headers together. I am using dynamic table.

Regards

Comment: And what is ID of second header?

Comment: for the second header id is given as header2

Comment: If its ID is `header2`, then you can use `$("#summarytab,#header2").freezeHeader();`

Comment: still it takes first header only

Comment: Have you checked docs for this plugin? Maybe it always works only with first element...

Comment: After generating 2nd table, you need to call `$("#header2").freezeHeader()`, else it won't work, as 2nd table is dynamically generated.

Comment: Fixed using stickytableheaders.js